# javascript get time information from Date object

Tags: javascript, time

I have time data: `"2018-11-11T16:02:21.857Z"`

From this data, I want to do this:

```
console.log('year: ' + something) // year: 2018
console.log('month: ' + something) // month: 11
console.log('day: ' + something) // day: 11
console.log('hour: ' + something) // hour: 16
console.log('min: ' + something) // min: 02
console.log('sec: ' + something) // sec: 21
```

Is there good way to do this?

I don't care using jQuery or not.

Do I need to do `string manipulation` or something?

If answer is yes, I'll do that.

But I think there might be some better way to do this.

Comment: Either parse string or pass the whole string to javascript Date object and use it's methods. Also depends on if you want local time or the UTC time in the string. For local definitely need Date object

Comment: I guess the first thing you should really do is to look at the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split up the date:

```
 const [day, time] = date.split("T");
 const [year, month, day] = day.split("-");
 const [hour, min, sec] = time.split(".")[0].split(":");
```

Comment: The OP was asking a good way to do it... `:/` Seriously, with 51k rep, didn't expect such a poor answer.

Comment: @praveen I don't know a better way. If you use the `Date` constructor you'd have to make sure that the timezone is right, that the month gets incremented and that zeros get padded in. That will take more code and is more likely to fail than the simple string manipulation above.

Comment: Ah, gotcha... `:)`